# Maxima of sum of exponential.

Tags: calculus

I want to find the maxima of $f=e^{-x}+e^{-2x}$, $x \ge 0$. I know the maximum happens at $x=0$, however when I differentiate and equate to zero I get : $\,e^{x}=-2$ which leads to $x=\ln(-2)$. Can any one point why the differentiation method doesn't lead to the correct answer?

Comment: How do you know? Observe that the value of $e^{-x}+e^{-2x}$ increases as $x$ decreases

Comment: I guess one of the powers should be positive?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Correct and @$x=0$, both $e^{-x}$ and $e^{-2x}$ are maximum, that's why the maximum (2) occurs at $x=0$. My question was to know why I can't get the maximum with differentiation.

Comment: Or maybe the definition of $f$ for negative $x$ is something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$f'(x)=-e^{-x}-2e^{-2x}=-e^{-2x}(e^x+2)=-\frac{e^x+2}{e^{2x}}$$ is *negative* for all $x$ in the domain of definition of $f$, so $f$ is strictly decreasing. Then $f$ has a maximum precisely if its given domain of definition has a least element, in this case $0$.

We can only use the first derivative test (setting the first derivative equal to $0$ and solving) at points on the **interior** of the domain of definition. Indeed, your work shows that $f$ has no maximum on the positive numbers. However, if we look to the single *boundary* point of the domain of definition (namely $x=0$), we can manually show that $f$ has a maximum there (using an argument like the one I gave above). We simply can't apply the first derivative test there, and this example is an excellent reason why.

More generally, suppose $D\subseteq\Bbb R$, and that $g:D\to\Bbb R$ is a function that is differentiable in the interior of $D$ and continuous on $D$. Then if $g$ obtains a maximum, it will be either at a critical point in the interior of $D$, or at a point on the boundary of $D$.

Comment: Thanks. Does it matter at all if $f=e^{-x}-e{-2x}$ instead?. I'm reading a textbook now and they have a maxima for this.

Comment: Indeed, that makes a difference (assuming you mean $f=e^{-x}-e^{-2x}$). In that case, $$f'(x)=-e^{-2x}(e^x-2),$$ which has its only zero at $x=\ln 2$. The second derivative test shows this to be a maximum.

Comment: if $x \geq 0$, then 0 is in the domain of definition.

Comment: True, but you said "$x>0$" in your post, previously.

Comment: My bad, I edited the question. So $f$ now should have a maxima at 0 and minimum at infinity. But why I can't get that with differentiation.

Comment: See my updated post. (What do you mean by "at $\infty$"?)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So If $f$ is strictly decreasing, then the maximum always happens at the least element in the domain of definition (0 in this case), is this correct?. $f$ goes to zero as $x$ goes to $\infty$, that's why I thought the minimum happens there.

Comment: Correct (if there *is* such an element), and similarly, the *minimum* of a strictly decreasing function always happens at the *greatest* element of its given domain of definition (if there *is* such an element). However, saying "$x\ge0$" typically indicates $x\in[0,+\infty)$, so your domain (as written) has no greatest element, and your function has no minimum.

Comment: Thanks alot for the great answer and discussion.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer, if you like it. Welcome to math.SE!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)= e^{-x}+e^{-2x}$ then 
$$
f'(x)=-e^{-x}-2e^{-2x}=-e^{-x}( 1+2e^{-x})=0 
$$
implies 
$
( 1+2e^{-x})=0
$ or $
e^{-x}=0
$. But it's impossible.  Then $f(x)$  doesn't have a minimum in $\mathbb{R}$. And as we know that $f$ is decreasing, $f$ has no minimum in $(0,\infty)$!